# Condition number of matrix is $1$ iff $A^TA=\alpha I$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, condition-number

I am trying to prove the following:

> The condition number $\kappa_p(A)=1$ for $A$ an matrix iff  $A^TA=\alpha I$ for some scalar number $\alpha\neq 0$.

I read somewhere on the internet that I somehow have to involve the singular value decomposition but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: What does the $p$ mean in $\kappa_p$?

Comment: sorry, $\kappa_p(A)=\|A\|_p\|A^{-1}\|_p$ where $\|A\|_p=sup_{\|x\|_p=1}\|Ax\|$

Comment: If you want a condition that *actually* applies for any $p$, note that $\kappa_p(A) = 1$ if and only if there is an $\alpha$ such that $\|Ax\|_p = \alpha \|x\|_p$ for every vector $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $\kappa$ is the condition number (with respect to the Euclidean norm), then
$$
\kappa(A) = \frac{\sigma_1(A)}{\sigma_n(A)}
$$
Where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_n$ denote the highest and lowest *singular values* of $A$, respectively.  It's clear that $\kappa(A) = 1$ if and only if $\sigma_1 = \sigma_n$.

*Now*, consider the singular value decomposition.

Comment: Ok, but in our exercise we have to prove this for any p-norm and not just euclidean norm.

Comment: Well, it's *not true* for any value of $p$ except for $p=2$, so that's not going to happen

Comment: You can verify that for any $p \neq 2$, there will be a rotation matrix $A$ for which $\kappa_p(A) \neq 1$.  In particular, it suffices to consider the rotation by $45^\circ$.