# If the condition number of a matrix is minimized then the matrix is orthogonalized?

Tags: optimization, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, condition-number

I know that if a square matrix is orthogonal, then its condition number is 1. I was wondering if the converse is true ? I have a non-square structured matrix and I want that the matrix be orthogonal by rows. In order to construct an orthogonal matrix, preserving its structure, I propose an optimization problem which minimizes the condition number. I achieve good results, however I don't known if by minimizing the condition number I always obtain an orthogonal matrix ( orthogonal by rows). My assumption is correct ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of "quasi-orthogonal".

Comment: A matrix will have condition number $1$ if and only if the dot product of every pair of rows (equivalently columns) is orthogonal **and** each row (column) has the same length.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1944926/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Since you say **If and only if**, can I conclude that if the condition number is minimized, i.e tends to 1, then the matrix will be orthogonal ?

Comment: you can't since in an orthogonal matrix (under the usual definition of an orthogonal matrix), the rows of a matrix have length $1$.

Comment: Ok, I can't obtain a orthogonal matrix, i.e $AA^T=I$, but I can obtain a matrix whose transpose is closely related to its inverse, i.e $AA^T=\lambda I$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, right ?

Comment: @cabeta14 right. To put it another way, you necessarily have a multiple of an orthogonal matrix; in particular $A/\|A\|$ will necessarily be orthogonal.

Comment: Got it, thank you @Omnomnomnom